# Typescript function param type depending on other param

Tags: typescript

I want to make my first param on createEventOnTopic function to help me to select a correct event inside the second param (Message interface)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFIAcCWwIwLwwNoHJ7OAFoBGHAGhj0RUICZyBdGAQzVEigG4AoAUwA8EIAE6woATwS8YAFWrAMcSbxAAzOPIhZmYcQx7d20GLwBuvMFAhyCxRbmYATRwH0IIALa8oACyRgAc3JKYV4PEHM3T28-QJwmVhgjLj5BETFlGABRc0sbFDtMCSk1E1yrfOBibV19bkNwYzMLCvlaexwnVx1xX38gihxQ8MievriEtkaUgSFRJSls8sr2ouVS5strNpq9A1n0mH8oXmFVZmBpAFleCAhmAOkAb24YN7KWgC4YaGF+nneMEczCgzG+PR4AF96qoAK5gYBQJDgJKhEG8HItADyYEqAAp8ChvpUKF47g9eN8buTHgBKb6mEBIRwwF7caGGNEnTGWHH4qgEEjBJ4fSzfTrOKJecYDIEgsGUHo4GCQ2k8YBcjHlPnyPECmikCgizZQcVdFxjWKy4Ggs26ZWqgz1bhAA)

```
const topics = ['topic-1', 'topic-2',] as const;
export type Topic = typeof topics[any];

const eventsTopic1 = ['add_something', 'remove_something'] as const;
export type EventTopic1 = typeof eventsTopic1[any];

const eventsTopic2 = ['add_anything', 'remove_anything'] as const;
export type EventTopic2 = typeof eventsTopic2[any];

export interface Message {
    event: string;
    data: any;
}

function createEventOnTopic(topic: Topic, message: Message): void {

}
```

I want to use id like this:

```
createEventOnTopic('topic-1', { event: 'add_something', data: 'any' }); // Ok
createEventOnTopic('topic-1', { event: 'add_anything', data: 'any' }); // Error, because its an event from the 'topic-2'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wQK6Ym) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the example code to demonstrate the failing use cases. Let me know.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you a lot!